# Permutations: a unique combination of 5 computer parts

Tags: combinatorics

I have 5 components: 
CPUx2
GPUx5
RAMx3
HDDx3
SDDx3

16 all together scattered over 5 groups. I need only one of each category for a PC.

How many setup ups are possible?

I keep thinking about:

n!/(k!(n-k)!

but this would include the chance to end up with 2 CPU's. Is this even about Permutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) states that if one event can occur in $m$ ways and another task can be performed independently of the first in $n$ ways, then there are $mn$ ways of performing both tasks.

In this problem, you have five tasks to perform:

1. Choose one of the two CPU's.
2. Choose one of the five GPU's.
3. Choose one of the three RAM's.
4. Choose one of the three HDD's.
5. Choose one of the three SDD's.

Assuming these choices can be made independently (that is, the choice of one item does not preclude the choice of another), apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to determine the number of PC's you could construct by choosing one item from each type of component.

> There are $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 270$ possible ways to construct a PC using one of the two CPU's, one of the five GPU's, one of the three RAM's, one of the three HDD's, and one of the three SDD's.

**Additional Remarks:**

The Multiplication Principle is more basic than permutations or combinations.

A $k$-permutation is an arrangement of $k$ objects selected from a set with $n$ objects.  The number of $k$-permutations is found by applying the Multiplication Principle.  There are $n$ ways of choosing the first object in the sequence, $n - 1$ ways of choosing the second object from those that remain in the set, $n - 2$ ways of choosing the third object from those that remain in the set, and so forth.  There are $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ ways to choose the $k$th object.  Hence, by the Multiplication Principle, the number of $k$-permutations is
$$P(n, k) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1) = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)(n - k)!}{(n - k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
A $k$-combination is a subset of $k$ objects selected from a set with $n$ objects.  We can select a sequence of $k$ objects in $P(n, k)$ objects.  However, the order in which we choose the objects of a subset does not matter.  Since we can select $k$ different objects in $k!$ orders, the number of $k$-combinations is
$$\binom{n}{k} = C(n, k) = \frac{1}{k!}P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$

Comment: YES. Thank you so much, I should stop thinking about maths when I should actually go to sleep. Foolish mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 CPU, 5 GPU, 3 RAM, 3 HDD, and 3 SDD. How may ways are there to choose one thing out of two things? How many ways are there to choose one thing out of five things? How many ways are there to choose one thing out of n things in general?

Once you understand this, just multiply all of your answers for each of the five groups.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication rule is what you are looking for. It gives the following answer to your counting Problem:

$$2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 270$$